# EGL image creation and deletion is it an overhead?

Tags: 3d, opengl-es-2.0

In our application we create new EGL image for each new frame and destroy the same 
is this an overhead ?

We are rendering video data and the video buffer is updated each frame hence we create new EGL image for each frame.

Is the approach of creating and destroying EGL images for each frame correct?

Please let me know your opinion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi
what is the scope to not render directly to "screen"? Are you saving the frames somehow?

Comment: Hi , we create EGL image from a client buffer that contains raw video frame data and the client buffer newly created for each frame due to which we create and destroy egl images for each frame. Also to render on screen we create texture from EGL image and then call glDraw. We are not saving any frames once data is on texture we deleted egl image